# Is it possible to create a list of numbers/letters in an if-statement without having to create multiple conditions?

Tags: c, if-statement

(Probably noob-ish question by hey you live you learn)

So what I'm trying to do is make a list of values I want to check without having to create multiple conditions like you usually have to do:

```c
if (a == 0 || a == 1 || a == 2 ... || a == 9) {
    // Code
}
```

Where you could probably do something like this:

```c
if (a == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)) {
    // Code
}
```

I couldn't find any posts on this topic and I once tried this myself at one point and it worked but nowadays it doesn't. Is it possible (Or still possible) to do something like this or in a way similar to this in an if-statement?

Comment: `0 <= a && a <= 9` ?

Comment: Maybe doing a loop can simplify your case, but I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: There are might be solutions which are suitable to a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (a) {
    case 1: case 2: case 3:
    case 4: case 5: case 6:
    case 7: case 8: case 9:
        // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accumulate possible values in an array and iterate over that array in a function that would OR-compare each element:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool cmp(int a, const int *arr, size_t size) {
    while (--size) {
        if (a == *arr++) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int values[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    if (cmp(a, values, 5)) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
}
```

By using a macro and a compound literal that array could be created on-stack and it's size could be calculated within the macro, like so:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool _cmp(int a, const int *arr, size_t size) {
    while (--size) {
        if (a == *arr++) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
#define cmp(a, ...)  _cmp(a, (int[]){__VA_ARGS__}, sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    if (cmp(a, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
}
```